# Prove or disprove that the language $L = \{xcy\, | \, x,y\in \{a,b,c\}^\star, |x|_a = |y|_b \}$ is context free

Tags: context-free

Let me cross post my question from math.stackexchange, since I feel this community is more related to the field.

Title is self explanatory. I want to know is the language $L = \{xcy \,| \,x,y\in \{a,b,c\}^\star, |x|_a = |y|_b \}$ is context-free.

I tried to prove that is not context-free using a proof by contradiction. Assuming that it is context-free we may apply the pumping lemma on the word
$$a^pcb^p\,,$$
where $p$ is the pumping length of $L$.

Letting $a^pcb^p = z_1u_1vu_2z_2$, where
$$\begin{gather}
z_1u^k_1vu^k_2z_2\,,\quad \text{for } k=0,1,2,\ldots \\
|u_1u_2| > 0 \quad \text{and} \quad |u_1vu_2| \leq p
\end{gather}\,.$$ I took cases on the consistency of $u_1u_2$; i.e. if it consists only of $a$'s or if it has a $c$.
Every case, except the follwing

- $u_1u_2$ consists of $a$ and $b$ but no $c$

wields a contradiction. The above case seems to produce no contradiction. Hence my method failed.

Do you know if the language $L$ is context-free? Could you explain how to obtain the answer?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: should I delete one of them?

Comment: That would be my preference, yes (but not one that has been answered).  In the future, if you post on the wrong site, please address any feedback you've received and delete the question from the other sites before posting on a new one (if they haven't received any answers), or request migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with *the* context-free language for beginners $\{ a^nb^n \mid n\ge 0\}$.

> $S\to aSb\mid \varepsilon$

Instead end with the symbol $c$ in the middle.

> $S\to aSb\mid c$

Now sprinkle the left and right parts with free $b,c$ and free $a,c$ respectively.

> $S\to aSb\mid c \mid bS\mid cS\mid Sa\mid Sc $

And I think we are actually ready to go!

Answer (score 5):

Well this is a basic context-free language and you should easily realize it's context-free, I guess what confused you is that $x,y\in\{a,b,c\}^*$ and the word is $xcy$ so you didn't know how to deal with the $c$, I recommend for questions like this you try to solve it in the form $x\#y$ where $\#\notin\Sigma^*$ and then solve the original problem.

---

Think about your problem like this: for each $a$ you read in $x$ insert $0$ to the stack, non-deterministically guess when the $x$ ends (by seeing the letter $c$), and from now on for each $b$ you read in $y$ remove $0$ from the stack, at the end if the stack is empty then the word is in the language. As a tip, try to prove this language $L=\{x\#y:x,y\in\{a,b,c\}^*,|x|_a=|y|_b\}$ is context-free.

---

This is a PDA that describes your language:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking a construction with a context free-grammar. Nice approach though.